# What is the difference between "available" noise power and noise power?

Tags: noise

I think of noise power as the noise voltage (RMS) squared.

From max power transfer theorem you arrive at the well known equation for available noise power at the input of some electronic component which is impedance matched to the source.

P_available=k* T * Bandwidth

Most tutorials on noise fail to explain why I care about this quantity or how I should think about.

If you could also provide some example calculations to show when this is relevant that would help.

Also, does this "available" noise power tell me anything about the RMS voltage noise at the input?

**EDIT**

The source of my confusion is the fact that available noise power is only a function of temperature and bandwidth. It seems to be a universal quantity (-174dBm) that you will find in all circuits. I dont get where this quantity is shown in a signal or circuit for example.

**EDIT #2**

[image]

This is what I am referring to when I say "available noise power". It is so dang confusing to me that "available thermal noise power" is always the same at a temperature T. Regardless of the magnitude of the voltage or current noise.

Comment: (you're only referring to thermal noise here, there's other types of noise, too. Ignoring that.) since that's the noise power that actually enters the system you care about, it's the only noise power you care about. It's power is proportional the RMS of the voltage observed in the component. I'm confused what other power you could be referring to!

Comment: I dont see how the available noise power is proportional to the RMS voltage observed in the component. The equation is only a function of temperature and bandwidth.'

Comment: it is. I don't see how it could be any other. Why do you have doubts regarding that?

Comment: @MaxW The available noise power from an external noise source is proportional to the RMS noise voltage observed at the input (assuming enough linearity or small-signal linearization) much like any power is proportional to RMS values of voltage- or current-like quantities.

Comment: -174dBm/Hz is not a constant, it's the available noise from a resistor at about 288K.  Cool your resistor and it drops, heat it and it rises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is what I am referring to when I say "available noise power". It is so dang confusing to me that "available thermal noise power" is always the same at a temperature T. Regardless of the magnitude of the voltage or current noise.*

Imagine you had two different resistances \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ , both at the same temperature but with different available noise powers in some bandwidth \$B\$. Take the resistor with lower available noise, heating it will increase the noise and you discover that heating it by \$\delta T\$ causes the available noise powers to be equal.  If you increase its temperature by \$\delta T/2\$ , you have a resistor that is hotter than the other, but with less available noise power.  Now connect these two resistors with an ideal filter around \$B\$ in series with an ideal transformer with turns ratio \$\sqrt{\frac{R_1}{R_2}}\$ so that they are impedance matched over \$B\$.   This causes the available noise power from each resistor in the bandwidth \$B\$ to be dissipated in the other, but by construction more power is flowing from the colder resistor to the hotter one.  Thus we have managed to cause energy to spontaneously flow from the cooler resistor to the hotter one, this is a problem!

This is why the available noise powers are independent of the value of the resistance. Hence the thevenin equivalent voltage noise is proportional to \$\sqrt{R}\$ and the thevenin equivalent current to \$\frac{1}{\sqrt{R}}\$

Answer (score 4):

> The source of my confusion is the fact that available noise power is only a function of temperature and bandwidth.

It's "thermal noise power"; never heard "available noise power". Yes, we model thermal noise as spectrally white, i.e. its power is proportional to bandwidth, and we model it as proportional to temperature.

> It seems to be a universal quantity (-174dBm)

It's -174 dBm/**Hz**. It's a noise power density: you get \$10^{-17.4}\$ milliwatt of power for every Hertz of bandwidth

> dont get where this quantity is shown in a signal or circuit for example.

It's not a discrete component, but a property of components, so it's not part of a circuit.

It's a part of a signal, any signal coming out of a non-zero-temperature component.

When you get into RF receiver design, you will see that thing being added to *every single component's output*, if the input is not that much stronger that the noise power can be safely neglected.

> Also, does this "available" noise power tell me anything about the RMS voltage noise at the input?

yes. "Power = mean square of voltage amplitude" is true for any signal, not just noise.

Comment: Your answer is very helpful I appreciate it. If you refer to the picture I added in the edit, you can see what I mean by available noise power. I am currently trying to calculate a noise figure of an ADC front end, and the very concept of "available power" ,be it signal or noise power, is still somewhat confusing to me. Any extra tid-bits of knowledge or explanation on the subject would be appreciated.

Comment: so, there's no conflict here: the noise power is kBT. The power ratio of noise and signal is the same in analog and digital. You write "confusing that power is the same regardless of voltage", but *voltage and power are inherently quadratically linked*. When the noise power stays the same, then the noise RMS voltage stays the same. *They're literally just the same information, expressed differently.*